# What is an http client and what cURL?

Tags: http

I'm beginning to learn to code.

Someone said to me: "cURL is the best http client".

To help me understand this sentence, I have two questions:

1. what is an HTTP CLIENT; and
2. what is cURL?

Comment: Have you done any research on this? A simple google search would have helped.

Comment: yes certainly but nothing got

Comment: Hard to believe. Anyway, a HTTP Client is something that you can use to consume a web service.

Comment: I am assuming OP is new, and not sure OP knows where to begin. I am giving him the benefit of the doubt and have proposed an edit to refine what I believe he is asking. To be fair to him I googled to find a "newbie level" to link to and, surprising, there were no clear answers in my first page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you are asking two things:

1. What is an HTTP CLIENT?

This is any program/application used make communications on the web using the  Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP). A common example is a browser.

2. What is cURL?

This a particular HTTP CLIENT designed to make HTTP communications on the web but built to be used via the command line of a terminal (command prompt).

If you perform a search for these topics, you will easily be able to find more in depth explanations about each.